# "Can't place call because this number is no longer registered on WhatsApp" when trying to call on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

For the past several days, I can't make WhatsApp calls. When I try, I get a message saying:

> Can't place call because this number is no longer registered on WhatsApp

So, I go to my account settings, and in "Two step Verification" it says:

> For added security, enable two-step verification, which will require a PIN when registering your phone number with WhatsApp again.

So I guess I need to re-register my phone. But how? If I try "change number", it won't accept the same number, it has to be a different one. Except I don't have a different number to use. And I definitely do not want to delete my account.

What do I do?

<sub>Relevant Details:

**Phone:** Xiaomi Redmi 3S

**Android version:** 6.0.1 (MIUI build 8.5.4.0)

**WhatsApp version:** 2.17.427</sub>

Comment: Does it happen by all calls, or is it too specific people? Maybe there person you are calling, doesn't have WhatsApp anymore. Are you able to send messages? If your number is not registered, WhatsApp wouldn't let you into the app without registering. So i am left to assume that the people you are trying to call don't have WhatsApp anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the message:

> Can't place call because **this** number is no longer registered on WhatsApp

the word "this" means "the number you're trying to call", not "your own number".

Calling other numbers will work.

A belated thanks goes to @aBochur for drawing my attention in this direction.